# Graphics are erased from Canvas when scrolling in ScrollPane

Tags: java, graphics, canvas, scrollpane

I have a `JFrame` that contains 4 instances of `ScrollPane`, each with its own `Canvas` and `BufferStrategy`.  When my drawing first takes place everything works as expected, but when I scroll in `ScrollPane` the graphics that are scrolled out of view are erased when I scroll them back into view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a Canvas and a ScrollPane. Use a JPanel and JScrollPane. Swing is double buffered by default.

Plus the code you posted has nothing to do with your custom painting so we can't guess what you might be doing wrong.

Post your SSCCE after making the changes and if you need more help.

Comment: Hi again @camickr... I really appreciate your help (now and in the past) but it seems you are always asking me for SSCCE.  I currently 5 different classes and it would take me hours to shrink it down to something small enough for you to run and navigate through easily.  I'll post the method I am currently using to draw on the Canvas.  I haven't ever used Swing and I don't know if I can grasp the difference I need to know before the morning when I have to turn this project in :(

Comment: @typoknig, That is NOT a SSCCE. You need to learn to create one in order to simplify the problem. Painting in Swing is the same as AWT except you override the paintComponent() method instead of the paint() method and you don't have to worry about double buffering. SO IT'S EASIER. See the Swing tutorial on painting (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). You should not use Thread.sleep. You should be using a Swing Timer. The tutorial also has a section on using Timers. Time to do some reading. JFrame is a Swing component so you are using Swing.

Comment: yes I realize none of what I posted is SSCCE.  I was saying that it would take me longer to make SSCCE than it would for me to convert everything to Swing.  I also realize the benefit of SSCCE, but when you are pressed for time it isn't an option.  Thanks again for your help, I'll try to implement your advice better on my next project.